# What's the point in QPainter::drawConvexPolgon

Tags: qt, qpainter, convex-hull

From the docs:

`QPainter` offers two methods of painting `QPolygons`: [`drawPolygon`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#drawPolygon) and [`drawConvexPolygon`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#drawConvexPolygon).

Nowhere in the documentation is it made clear what the difference between them is. Additionally, the `drawConvexPolygon` docs state

> If the supplied polygon is not convex, i.e. it contains at least one angle larger than 180 degrees, the results are undefined.

So... what is it for? I hoped the method would somehow find the convex hull of my polygon and paint that, however that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`QPainter::drawConvexPolygon()` documentation](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#drawConvexPolygon) says:

> On some platforms (e.g. X11), the drawConvexPolygon() function can be faster than the drawPolygon() function.

So,

- `drawPolygon()` is **more generic** as it also allows to paint non-convex polygons (but drawing might be slower)
- `drawConvexPolygon()` can only be used to draw convex polygons, but might be **faster** on specific platforms

For example, when doing 3D-rendering, you can use a [Polygon Mesh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_mesh) which consists of convex polygons only to make rendering simpler, in which case the faster `drawConvexPolygon()` would be the better choice (since you need to paint a large number of convex polygons).

Comment: Ah, so it depends on prior knowledge whether the polygon is convex or not.

Comment: Right - and depending on that, you should choose the one or the other method

Answer (score 1):

Determining which part of the polygon is the outside and inside (for filling purposes) makes different choices depending on if the polygon contains a convex region.  Think about how to determine the inside of a star shape vs. the inside of a rectangle.